# JSON Path to get value of next element in an array based on previous element?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonpath

Is there any way to write JSON Path to get value of next element in an array based on previous element ?

JSON :

```
[
   [
      "value11",
      "text1",
      "value12"
   ],
   [
      "value21",
      "text2",
      "value22"
   ],
   [
      "value31",
      "text3",
      "value32"
   ],
   [
      "value41",
      "text4",
      "value42"
   ]
]
```

Expected :

Path : $[0][if matches "searchtext"] next|previous

> Searchtext : text1 output (get next value) : value12 output (get
>   previous value) : value11
>
> Searchtext : text2 output (get next value) : value22 output (get
>   previous value) : value21

I'm using  https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath for implementation.

Thanks in advance.

-- Mani

Answer (score 0):

Got JSON Path : $[?(@[1] == "text1")].[0]